# Assigning object does not work through Rest/Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, version, eslint, ecma

I went to a trouble when doing hardcopy of an object.

```
let error = { ...err }
```

So when I wrote that way I received a warning from ESLint "Rest/spread properties are not supported until node.js 8.3.0" and nothing was assigned to my error variable.

I was sure that my node version is much higher than the required one, however I checked - it's ^14.1.0.

ESLint version - ^6.6.0.

Lots of forums said to configure ESLint to make it work, so I added first:

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=10.6.0"
}
```

And then:

```
"env": {
    "es6": true
},
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 9,
    "sourceType": "module"
}
```

However, it still doesn't work. **err** object is defined, when I try to implement in other ways it works, but when assigning
through Spread - it doesn't.

Does someone have any idea?

Thanks!

P.S. when console.log(err.name) I get `'CastError'`,
when I console.log(error.name) after `let error = { ...err }`,
I get undefined.

P.P.S. error inherits some properties from err, but property name is undefined.

P.P.P.S. the snippet is

```
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
    ...

    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        let error = { ...err }
        if (error.name === 'CastError') {
            error = handleCastErrorDB(error)
        }
        sendErrorProd(error, res)
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't do what needed.
Thus, when I change if statement condition to `err.name === 'CastError'` instead of `error.name === 'CastError'` everything works.

Comment: It may be you have more than one version of Node installed, and however you are running your app, you are using the older version.  You could try logging out the version that your app is running in by adding this: `console.log(process.version);
` before your `let error = {...err}` line.

Comment: Just tried, still doesn't work  says 14.1.0

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty weird...ESLint complaining about the node version is one thing, but your variable not getting its assigned value is another.  Your ESlint could be misconfigured, but if you're really running Node 14, then the rest spread assignment should work.  If you're using build tools or transpilers (webpack, babel) the problem may be there.

Comment: @MattMorgan you’re right, something weird happens there, some err properties also are missing ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem on this Udemy course, the solution is:

```
let error = Object.assign(err)
```

Comment: Yeah that’s a basic way but the problem is that i can’t find the reason why spread operator doesn’t work.